# How to avoid building C++ static libraries in Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I've tried various combinations of `--dynamic_mode=fully` in the command line and `linkstatic = 0` in `cc_library` and `cc_binary` rules, but haven't managed to avoid building static libraries (`.a`) when building Bazel projects. While binaries are indeed linked dynamically, the `.a` files are built nonetheless, taking up a lot of time and space (on the shared cache).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: it seems that the problem was the wildcard `build //...`. It triggers linking *both* the static and the dynamic library of each `cc_library` rule. If you add `tags = ["manual"]` to the libraries, and build with `--dynamic_mode=fully`, static `.a` libraries won't build automatically anymore, but `.so` will still be created as depended on by `cc_binary` targets.